# Python API Rate Limiting - How to Limit API Calls Globally

Tags: python, rate-limiting

I'm trying to restrict the API calls in my code. I already found a nice python library `ratelimiter==1.0.2.post0`
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ratelimiter

However, this library can only limit the rate in local scope. i.e) in function and loops

```
# Decorator
@RateLimiter(max_calls=10, period=1)
def do_something():
    pass


# Context Manager
rate_limiter = RateLimiter(max_calls=10, period=1)

for i in range(100):
    with rate_limiter:
        do_something()
```

Because I have several functions, which make API calls, in different places, I want to limit the API calls in **global** scope.

For example, suppose I want to limit the APIs call to *one time per second*. And, suppose I have functions `x` and `y` in which two API calls are made.

```
@rate(...)
def x():
   ...

@rate(...)
def y():
   ...
```

By decorating the functions with the `limiter`, I'm able to limit the rate against the two functions.

However, if I execute the above two functions sequentially, it looses track of the number of API calls in **global** scope because they are unaware of each other. So, `y` will be called right after the execution of `x` without waiting another second. And, this will violate the *one time per second* restriction.

Is there any way or library that I can use to limit the rate **globally** in python?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After all, I implemented my own `Throttler` class. By proxying every API request to the `request` method, we can keep track of all API requests. Taking advantage of passing function as the `request` method parameter, it also caches the result in order to reduce API calls.

```
class TooManyRequestsError(Exception):
    def __str__(self):
        return "More than 30 requests have been made in the last five seconds."


class Throttler(object):
    cache = {}

    def __init__(self, max_rate, window, throttle_stop=False, cache_age=1800):
        # Dict of max number of requests of the API rate limit for each source
        self.max_rate = max_rate
        # Dict of duration of the API rate limit for each source
        self.window = window
        # Whether to throw an error (when True) if the limit is reached, or wait until another request
        self.throttle_stop = throttle_stop
        # The time, in seconds, for which to cache a response
        self.cache_age = cache_age
        # Initialization
        self.next_reset_at = dict()
        self.num_requests = dict()

        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        for source in self.max_rate:
            self.next_reset_at[source] = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.window.get(source))
            self.num_requests[source] = 0

    def request(self, source, method, do_cache=False):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()

        # if cache exists, no need to make api call
        key = source + method.func_name
        if do_cache and key in self.cache:
            timestamp, data = self.cache.get(key)
            logging.info('{} exists in cached @ {}'.format(key, timestamp))

            if (now - timestamp).seconds < self.cache_age:
                logging.info('retrieved cache for {}'.format(key))
                return data

        # <--- MAKE API CALLS ---> #

        # reset the count if the period passed
        if now > self.next_reset_at.get(source):
            self.num_requests[source] = 0
            self.next_reset_at[source] = now + datetime.timedelta(seconds=self.window.get(source))

        # throttle request
        def halt(wait_time):
            if self.throttle_stop:
                raise TooManyRequestsError()
            else:
                # Wait the required time, plus a bit of extra padding time.
                time.sleep(wait_time + 0.1)

        # if exceed max rate, need to wait
        if self.num_requests.get(source) >= self.max_rate.get(source):
            logging.info('back off: {} until {}'.format(source, self.next_reset_at.get(source)))
            halt((self.next_reset_at.get(source) - now).seconds)

        self.num_requests[source] += 1
        response = method()  # potential exception raise

        # cache the response
        if do_cache:
            self.cache[key] = (now, response)
            logging.info('cached instance for {}, {}'.format(source, method))

        return response
```

Comment: nice work! Does this work for individual IPs, or globally?

Comment: how would you even use this?

Answer (score 23):

I had the same problem, I had a bunch of different functions that calls the same API and I wanted to make rate limiting work globally. What I ended up doing was to create an empty function with rate limiting enabled.

**PS:** I use a different rate limiting library found here: https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/

```
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry

# 30 calls per minute
CALLS = 30
RATE_LIMIT = 60

@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=CALLS, period=RATE_LIMIT)
def check_limit():
''' Empty function just to check for calls to API '''
return
```

Then I just call that function at the beginning of every function that calls the API:

```
def get_something_from_api(http_session, url):
    check_limit()
    response = http_session.get(url)
    return response
```

If the limit is reached, the program will sleep until the (in my case) 60 seconds have passed, and then resume normally.

Comment: I notice the question asks for a GLOBAL rate limit, but this solution is only for rate limiting in one specific process/thread

Answer (score 2):

Many API providers constrain developers from making too many API calls.

**Python ratelimit** packages introduces a function decorator preventing a function from being called more often than that allowed by the API provider.

```py
from ratelimit import limits

import requests
TIME_PERIOD = 900   # time period in seconds
    
@limits(calls=15, period=TIME_PERIOD)
def call_api(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('API response: {}'.format(response.status_code))
    return response
```

**Note: This function will not be able to make more then 15 API call within a 15 minute time period.**

Comment: This answer misses the point of the question, doesn't it? The question was about how to prevent exceeding a rate limit globally in a script, not with one function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sunil answer, you need to add @sleep_and_retry decorator, otherwise your code will break when reach the rate limit:

```
@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=0.05, period=1)
def api_call(url, api_key):
    r = requests.get(
        url,
        headers={'X-Riot-Token': api_key}
        )
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception('API Response: {}'.format(r.status_code))
    return r
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of fancy libraries that will provide nice decorators, and special safety features, but the below should work with `django.core.cache` or any other cache with a `get` and `set` method:

```
def hit_rate_limit(key, max_hits, max_hits_interval):
    '''Implement a basic rate throttler. Prevent more than max_hits occurring
    within max_hits_interval time period (seconds).'''
    # Use the django cache, but can be any object with get/set
    from django.core.cache import cache
    hit_count = cache.get(key) or 0
    logging.info("Rate Limit: %s --> %s", key, hit_count)
    if hit_count > max_hits:
        return True
    cache.set(key, hit_count + 1, max_hits_interval)
    return False
```

Comment: Hi. This can not work, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77860332/983222

Answer (score 0):

Using the Python standard library:

```py
import threading
from time import time, sleep

b = threading.Barrier(2)

def belay(s=1):
    """Block the main thread for `s` seconds."""
    while True:
        b.wait()
        sleep(s)

def request_something():
    b.wait()
    print(f'something at {time()}')

def request_other():
    b.wait()
    print(f'or other at {time()}')
    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    thread = threading.Thread(target=belay)
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    # request a lot of things
    i = 0
    while (i := i+1) < 5:
        request_something()
        request_other()
```

There's about `s` seconds between each timestamp printed. Because the main thread waits rather than sleeps, time it spends responding to requests is unrelated to the (minimum) time between requests.

Answer (score 0):

[@speedlane answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748687/python-api-rate-limiting-how-to-limit-api-calls-globally#answer-65243062) can not work as expected. For eg. with max 4 hits / 1 sec:

- call at time 1 (`t1`) 0: cache value set to 1 until `t1 + 1`
- call at `t2` 0.9 : cached value set to 2 until `t2 + 1`  (1.9)
- call at `t3` 1.8 : cached value set to 3 until `t3 + 1`  (2.8)
- call at `t4` 2.7 : cached value set to 4 until `t4 + 1`  (3.7)
- call at `t5` 3.6 : cached value set to 5 until `t4 + 1`  (4.6)
- call at `t6` 4.5 : it fails because cached value is 5 and is greater than max hits (4).
  **But it should not**: it's just the second hit until t6 - 1 sec = 3.5.

The problem is that you re-add a `max_hit_interval` at you expiration cache date.

Here is a working exemple strongly inspired by proposed answer if you don't want an extra package:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
import hashlib
import random
import time
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.utils.timezone import now


class SomeClass:    
    config = {
        "api_url": "https://some-app.fr/v2/",  # base url of the API
        "rate_limit_hits": 4,  # number of requests allowed per rate_limit_seconds
        "rate_limit_seconds": 1,  # number of seconds to raise the rate_limit_hits
        "timeout": 15,  # number of seconds before timeout
    }

    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.config["api_key"] = api_key

    def pass_rate_limit(self):
        """Ensure that the rate limit won't be raised"""
        rate_limit_hits = self.config.get("rate_limit_hits", 0)
        rate_limit_seconds = self.config.get("rate_limit_seconds", 0)
        if not rate_limit_seconds or not rate_limit_hits:
            return True
        key = hashlib.md5(
            (self.config["api_url"] + self.config["api_key"][0:8]).encode("utf8")
        ).hexdigest()
        key = f"SomeClass-{key}-hits"
        hits = cache.get(key) or []
        first_relevant_hit_dt = now() - timedelta(seconds=rate_limit_seconds)
        relevant_hits = [dt for dt in hits if dt >= first_relevant_hit_dt]
        if len(relevant_hits) >= rate_limit_hits:
            pause_for = 0
            oldest_relevant_hit = relevant_hits[0]
            free_place_available_at = oldest_relevant_hit + timedelta(seconds=rate_limit_seconds)
            pause_for = free_place_available_at - now()
            if pause_for.seconds <= 0:
                pause_for = pause_for.microseconds / 1000000
            print(f"I am paused for {pause_for:0.4f} at ", now())
            time.sleep(pause_for)
            return self.pass_rate_limit()
        relevant_hits.append(now())
        # because depending the cache used, you can't use 1 seconds or less.
        cache.set(key, relevant_hits, 2 if rate_limit_seconds < 2 else rate_limit_seconds)
        return True

test = SomeClass("osef")

for i in range(0,12):
    print("called at: ", now())
    test.pass_rate_limit()
    print("executed at: ", now())
    time.sleep(random.random() / 4)  # fake API duration process for eg
```

Output:

> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.088826+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.089861+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.206402+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.207634+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.254885+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.255998+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.463253+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.464364+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:58.470950+00:00
> I am paused for 0.6179 at  2024-01-22 13:46:58.471554+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.091214+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.216833+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.218037+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.311481+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.312633+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.315305+00:00
> I am paused for 0.1479 at  2024-01-22 13:46:59.316001+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.465314+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:46:59.693648+00:00
> I am paused for 0.3965 at  2024-01-22 13:46:59.694304+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:47:00.092423+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:47:00.242771+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:47:00.243341+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:47:00.331994+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:47:00.333285+00:00
> called at:  2024-01-22 13:47:00.433985+00:00
> I am paused for 0.0301 at  2024-01-22 13:47:00.434795+00:00
> executed at:  2024-01-22 13:47:00.466349+00:00