# Telegram API flooding error when using for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, telegram, telethon

I am extracting data from 700+ Telegram groups and channels using Telethon in PyCharm. I am using a for loop to loop through all entities and extract the data needed for my analysis.

The code works fine when the list object "groups_list" contains a lower number of groups and channels. However, when "groups_list" contains all 700+ groups/channels I get the error messages after a few minutes.

My guess is that I am flooding Telegram's API with too many requests. Is there a way I can alter my code so it works more effective?

```
# Define an infinite number to get all messages in channel/group
infinite_number = float('inf')

# Making an empty list for each column/variable I want to extract from the API
message_id = []
message = []
channel_id =[]
reply_to =[] 
time = []
retweet_count = []
view_count = []
user_id = []
retweet = []

# For loop that iterates over list of groups i.e. "list_groups" and extract Telegram data
for x in list_groups:
    chats = client.get_messages(x, infinite_number)
    if len(chats):
        for chat in chats:
            message_id.append(chat.id)
            message.append(chat.message)
            channel_id.append(chat.peer_id)
            reply_to.append(chat.reply_to_msg_id)
            time.append(chat.date)
            retweet_count.append(chat.forwards)
            view_count.append(chat.views)
            user_id.append(chat.from_id)
            retweet.append(chat.fwd_from)

data ={'message_id':message_id, 'message':message, 'channel_id': channel_id, 'reply_to_msg_id':reply_to, 'time':time, 'retweet_count':retweet_count, 'view_count':view_count, 'user_id':user_id, 'retweet':retweet}

# Convert lists til data.frame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```
raise errors.FloodWaitError(request=r, capture=diff)
telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.FloodWaitError: A wait of 85313 seconds is required (caused by ResolveUsernameRequest)
```

PS: Political science student new to Python :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python API Rate Limiting - How to Limit API Calls Globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748687/python-api-rate-limiting-how-to-limit-api-calls-globally) You'd just have to use the Telegram API documentation, or something like that, to find out what the rate limits are.

Comment: Hi @RandomDavis. Thanks for the input. I did a "nasty" workaround where I split the +700 groups and channels into small batches of 50 entities and then ran the code. It did the trick. No error messages. Subsequently I just used rbind() in R (my primary language) to append the data frames.